# How to generalize a common function in parent class?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two classes 'A' & 'B'.
These two classes has some functions and one common function i.e 'toJson()'.

I have created a parent class 'Json' for to convert a class to json.

```
class Json
{
    public function toJSON() {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

class A extends Json{

    private $a;
    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->a = $input;
    }
    //getter & setter
}

class B extends Json{
    private $b;
    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->b = $input;
    }
    //getter & setter
}


$a = new A("A")->json();
$b = new B("B")->json();
```

i expected both class converted to json. But 'null' is returned.

I have added 'toJSON()' to both class. Its working as expected.

Is it possible to generalize the 'toJSON()'?

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `$a = new A("A")->toJSON();` ?

Comment: `$a = new A("A")` and then `$a->toJSON();` and it returns `[]` because you can't access private properties. See [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski `$a = new A("A")->toJSON();` will throw an error.

Comment: You can use a Trait instead: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php and just as its said: `$a = new A("A")->toJson()` is not right. Sure you tested this? Also your properties are private....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we skip your syntax errors and focus on the problem at hand, this all comes down to [property visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

You cannot access private properties outside of that class, including when dealing with inheritance.  You can change the properties `$a` and `$b` to protected or public to allow them to be accessible by the JSON class.

You can try using private here: https://3v4l.org/Vhr9M

You can try using protected here: https://3v4l.org/9neiQ

Comment: If the `get_object_vars` is used inside the class and then the results are exposed through another method (`toJSON()`) even in that case wouldn't work?

Comment: @HCK I posted sandbox links to show the difference.

Comment: @Davon I've just did and you are right. Eveyday you can learn something. I actually believe that if you use the property inside the class this would be available. Actually now that I see, the visibility problem is caused by the get_object_vars, so yeah that `protected` does the trick. Nice.

Comment: That's the major difference between private and protected.

Comment: @HCK I actually just saw your mention of get_object_vars,  this isn't related to get_object_vars, it's visibility in general.  A method in JSON cannot access private properties in A or B regardless, this shows an example of that: https://3v4l.org/5mAZX

Comment: I know, my aclaration was that at, at first, I thought that the trouble was related to 'private' properties used in a method and then exposed somewhere else. But then I realize that the trouble was caused when the `get_object_vars` was called, not because this method is the problem but when this method tries to access the object properties -and given that `$a`/`$b` was private- it returned and empty array.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Obs: Check [Davon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639814/7117697) answer to get to the root of the problem. Btw, that should be the accepted answer.

---

You are calling `json()` instead of `toJSON()` (how you declared it). Besides that, the properties `$a` and `$b` are not accessible when doing `get_object_vars()` because they are declared as `private`. Change them to `protected` instead:

```php
class Json
{
    public function toJSON() {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
        // or this?:  return json_enconde($this->a);
    }
}

class A extends Json {

    protected $a;

    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->a = $input;
    }

    //getter & setter
}

class B extends Json {
    protected $b;

    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->b = $input;
    }

    //getter & setter

}
```

Luego cuando hagas:

```php
$a = (new A("A"))->toJSON();
dd($a);
```

> "A"

```php
$b = (new B("B"))->toJSON();
dd($b);
```

> "B"

Comment: `new B("B")->toJSON();` this will not work because its not object but you can do like this `(new B("B"))->toJSON();` now its object without any name.

Comment: This still won't work, you're focusing on syntax errors instead of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `new A("A")->json();` will not work, you need to make a object or direct call wrapping in a bracket like `(new A("A"))->toJSON();`. You have method `toJSON` not `json`.You should use something like this

```
<?php
class Json
{
    private $v;
    public function toJSON($c) {
        $this->v = $c;
        return json_encode(get_object_vars( $this));
    }
}

class A extends Json{

    private $a;
    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->a = $input;
    }
    //getter & setter
}

class B extends Json{
    private $b;
    function __construct($input = null) {
        $this->b = $input;
    }
    //getter & setter
}


$a = (new A("A"))->toJSON([1,2,3]);
$b = (new B("B"))->toJSON([4,5,6]);
echo $a;
echo $b;
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1043714)